# React - How do I start a timer, then navigate a different route, then come back and have the timer still in sync with its original countdown?

Tags: reactjs, timer, countdowntimer

The title really says it all. I've seen some questions about how to keep a component from un-mounting, but I'm not sure that's exactly what I need (or at least not all that I need).

Right now I have the timer updating from a background thread so that when the browser tab goes into the background it doesn't fall asleep. But I also want it to continue counting when I go to a different screen in the app. (I'm making a time tracking app).

Can anyone tell me how to approach this?

Thanks

My full clock.js - unfortunately it's nested in some other components right now and would be a chore to lift the logic to the top level component.

The clock works in conjunction with a background task, which I've posted right below it.

```
import React, { useEffect, useState, useRef, useContext } from 'react'
import './Clock.css'
import useSound from 'use-sound';
import bark from '../../Sounds/bong.wav';
import tweet from '../../Sounds/bong.wav';
import gong from '../../Sounds/opening_gong.wav'
import SkipNext from '@material-ui/icons/SkipNextOutlined';
import Stop from '@material-ui/icons/StopOutlined';
import PausePresentation from '@material-ui/icons/PauseOutlined';
import PlayCircleOutline from '@material-ui/icons/PlayArrowOutlined';
import MainContext from '../../MainContext'
import myWorker from '../../test.worker';



function Clock(props) {

  const context = useContext(MainContext)
  let breakPrefs = context.prefs

  const [timer, setTimer] = useState({
    onBreak: false,
    firstPageLoad: true,
    isPaused: true,
    time: 0,
    timeRemaining: 0,
    cycle: 0,
    skipped: false
  })

  const [playBark] = useSound(bark,
    { volume: 0.65 }
  );

  const [playTweet] = useSound(tweet,
    { volume: 0.20 }
  );

  const [playGong] = useSound(gong,
    { volume: 0.20 }
  );


  



  //sets up a worker thread to keep the clock running accurately when browser is in background
  const worker = useRef()
  useEffect(() => {
    worker.current = new myWorker()
    return () => {
      worker.current.terminate();
    }
  }, [])

  //updates time remaining in state from the worker thread every second
  useEffect(() => {
    const eventHander = e => {
      if(e.data === true){
        //here is where the sound should play
       
      }else{
        setTimer((timer) => ({
          ...timer,
          timeRemaining: e.data
        }))
      }

    }

    worker.current.addEventListener('message', eventHander)
    return () => {
      worker.current.removeEventListener('message', eventHander)
    }
  }, [])



  //stops the countdown from resetting during certain UI events 
  let allowCountdownRestart = false
  useEffect(() => {
    if (allowCountdownRestart) {
      allowCountdownRestart = false
    } else {
      allowCountdownRestart = true
    }
  }, [props, allowCountdownRestart])

  useEffect(() => {
    allowCountdownRestart = false
  }, [breakPrefs, props.noClockStop, context.handleAddProject, context.currentProject]);



  //resets the timer when the user selects a new cycle
  //couldn't pass in [props.cycle] for this because of an issue when user selects the same cycle twice
  useEffect(() => {

    if (allowCountdownRestart) {
      worker.current.postMessage({ message: "start", "time": props.cycle * 60 })

      setTimer((timer) => ({
        ...timer,
        time: props.cycle * 60,
        timeRemaining: props.cycle * 60,
        cycle: props.cycle,
        onBreak: false
      }));

    }
  }, [props])

 

  //starts the timer after it's reset 
  useEffect(() => {
    if (timer.time > 0) {
      worker.current.postMessage({ message: "start", "time": timer.time })
    }
  }, [timer.time])

  //listens for when take break is pressed
  useEffect(() => {
    if(props.takeBreak !== 0){
      setTimer((timer) => ({
        ...timer,
        onBreak: true
      }))
    }
  

  }, [props.takeBreak])

  //handles the automatic switch to a break after a regular cycle 
  useEffect(() => {


    if (timer.time === 0 && !timer.firstPageLoad) {
      setTimeout(function () {
        if (timer.onBreak) {
          timer.onBreak = false
        } else {

          
          // const breakDuration = breakPrefs["break_duration"] * 60
          // if (breakDuration !== 0) {
          //   worker.current.postMessage({ message: "start", "time": breakDuration })
          //   setTimer((timer) => ({
          //     ...timer,
          //     onBreak: true,
          //     time: breakDuration,
          //     timeRemaining: breakDuration
          //   }));
          // }

          if (!timer.skipped) {
            props.updateDBWithTask(timer.cycle)
            props.subtractFromTimeUntilBreak(timer.cycle, false) 

          }
          setTimer((timer) => ({
            ...timer,
            skipped: false
          }));
        }
      }, 1000);

    } else {
      if (timer.time === timer.timeRemaining) {
        timer.firstPageLoad = false
        handleResume()
      }
    }
  }, [timer.time, timer.time === timer.timeRemaining])


  //determines which sound to play, and resets the timer to its original state at the end of a cycle.
  useEffect(() => {

    if (timer.timeRemaining === 0) {

      if(!timer.onBreak){
        playTweet()
      }

      setTimer((timer) => ({
        ...timer,
        time: 0,
        isPaused: true
      }));

    }
  }, [timer.timeRemaining])



  //listens for pause/unpause and updates timer accordingly
  useEffect(() => {
    if (timer.isPaused) {
      worker.current.postMessage({ message: "pause", "time": timer.timeRemaining })


    } else {
      worker.current.postMessage({ message: "start", "time": timer.timeRemaining })
    }
  }, [timer.isPaused])



  const handlePause = e => {
    setTimer({ ...timer, isPaused: true })
  }

 

  const handleResume = e => {
    if (timer.time !== 0) {
      setTimer({
        ...timer,
        isPaused: false
      })
    }
  }

  const handleSkip = () => {

    const elapsedMinutes = Math.floor((timer.time - timer.timeRemaining) / 60)
    const remainingSeconds = (timer.time - timer.timeRemaining) - elapsedMinutes * 60;
    const roundedMinutes = remainingSeconds > 30 ? elapsedMinutes + 1 : elapsedMinutes
    
    if(roundedMinutes > 0 && !timer.onBreak){
      props.updateDBWithTask(roundedMinutes)
      props.subtractFromTimeUntilBreak(roundedMinutes, true)
    }

    setTimer({ ...timer, skipped: true, timeRemaining: 0 })
    worker.current.postMessage({ message: "stop", "time": 0 })
  }

  const handleStop = () => {
    setTimer({ ...timer, onBreak: true, cycle: 0, timeRemaining: 0 })
    worker.current.postMessage({ message: "stop", "time": 0 })
  }




  const timeFormat = (duration) => {

    if (duration > 0) {
      var hrs = ~~(duration / 3600);
      var mins = ~~((duration % 3600) / 60);
      var secs = ~~duration % 60;
      var ret = "";
      if (hrs > 0) {
        ret += "" + hrs + ":" + (mins < 10 ? "0" : "");
      }
      ret += "" + mins + ":" + (secs < 10 ? "0" : "");
      ret += "" + secs;
      return ret;
    } else {
      return "00:00"
    }
  }


  return <>

    <div className="floatLeft">
      <div id="timer">

        {timer.onBreak ?
          <div><h2 className="display-timer-header">On Break </h2> <h2 className="display-timer">{timeFormat(timer.timeRemaining)}</h2></div>
          : <div><h3 className="display-timer-header"> Time Left </h3> <h3 ref={context.timerRef} className="display-timer">{timeFormat(timer.timeRemaining)}</h3></div>}


        <div className="toolbar-container">
          <div className={`toolbar-icons ${props.taskBarOpen ? "taskbar-open" : ""}`}>
            <i className="tooltip"><Stop className="toolbar-icon" onClick={handleStop}></Stop>
              <span className="tooltiptext">Stop/Cancel</span></i>
            {!timer.isPaused ?
              <i className="tooltip pause"><PausePresentation className="toolbar-icon" onClick={handlePause}></PausePresentation>
                <span className="tooltiptext pause-tooltip">Pause</span></i>
              :
              <i className="tooltip pause"><PlayCircleOutline className="toolbar-icon" onClick={handleResume}></PlayCircleOutline>
                <span className="tooltiptext">Resume</span></i>
            }
            <i className="tooltip"><SkipNext className="toolbar-icon" onClick={handleSkip} ></SkipNext>
              <span className="tooltiptext">Finish Early</span></i>

          </div>
        </div>

      </div>
    </div>

  </>
}




export default Clock;
```

backgroundtask.js

```
let myInterval;
/* eslint-disable-next-line no-restricted-globals */
self.onmessage = function(evt) {
    clearInterval(myInterval);

      if(evt.data.message === 'pause' || evt.data.message === 'stop' || evt.data.message === 'skip'){
        postMessage(evt.data.time)
      }

    if (evt.data.message == "start" || evt.data.message == "break") {
        var i = evt.data.time;
        myInterval = setInterval(function() {
            i--;
            postMessage(i);
        }, 1000);
        
    } 
  
};
```

Comment: So it will depend on where the timer update code is. Can you attach some snippets please?

Comment: Can you use `context`, `redux`, an API, or move the time state to a higher component in the tree?

Comment: unfortunately the way I have it now, the time keeping logic is located in one of the more deeply nested components.

Comment: I'm not sure how much posting code will help, I think I have an architecture/theory problem.

Comment: Any way to just keep the component from un-mounting? Or maybe open the tracking UI 'on top' of the timer UI?

Answer (score 1):

I believe if i am not mistaken you can just lift the logic relating to the time to a parent component.

```
  const App = () => {
     return (
        <>
          <Timer />
          <Route 1 />
          <Route 2 />
        <>
     )
  }
```

It's up to you if you want to hide the `Timer`, but as long as it's on the parent, nothing else can change it.

Answer (score 0):

You can resolve this issue via Context, by wrapping all components need to track time under this context (you can use any context is wrapped component for now)

EX (Snippet from context file)

```
  // firing request to pingPong API to update header data each 5 sec
  useInterval(() => {
    // You action
  }, YOUR_TIME);

  // context values
  const contextValue = useMemo(() => {
    return {
      state,
      myFunctionONEIFNeeded,
      myFunctionTWOIFNeeded,
      .
      .
    };
  }, [state]);

  return (
    <OnlineAssessmentContext.Provider value={contextValue}>
      {props.children}
    </OnlineAssessmentContext.Provider>
  );
```

for useInterval this is a custom hook we build it for interval (and you can replace it via any thing you like):

```
import React, {useEffect, useRef, useState, useCallback} from 'react';
import {v4  as uuid} from 'uuid';
const useInterval = (callback, delay) => {
  const savedCallback = useRef();

  const [id ,setId] = useState(uuid());
  // Remember the latest callback.
  savedCallback.current = callback;

  // Set up the interval.
  useEffect(() => {
    function tick() {
      savedCallback.current();
    }

    if (delay !== null) {
      let id = setInterval(tick, delay);
      return () => clearInterval(id);
    }
  }, [delay, id]);

  //This Function To Reset Time Interval Depend On Call Reset
  const reset = useCallback(()=>{
    setId(uuid());
  },[]);
  
  return reset;
}

export default useInterval;
```

====================

Important Note:
1- You need to make sure about re-rendering if there's any change in state and prefer to do the needed job without change a global context state, and you can think how you can optimize your update to fit needed

2- We useMemo in return function to prevent re-render else if the state is changed, usually we don't need to listen to function update else if we needed it, you can check or install why-did-you-render

Answer (score 0):

When you navigate to a different route you unload the old route and all of the components in it, thus losing the state associated with those components. The only way to persist state across route navigations is to maintain state above the route switch.

This can be done in a number of ways:

- Maintaining the state in a parent component and passing it through props.
- Using [Context](https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html) to provide a context to all child components. When providing state through a Context, the state can either be managed through the parent component and passed into the Context - or you can provide state-updating functions inside of the Context (as demonstrated within the linked documentation).
- Using a state-management library like [Redux](https://react-redux.js.org/). If your application state is complex, I would recommend looking into this - since managing complex state through a Context can be more cumbersome and error-prone. If your application is simple enough, this likely won't be an issue.